# Java, using class files from a .jar

Tags: java, jar, package, filepath, javac

so i am trying to use classes from a jar file i downloaded. The jar file is not in the same directory as the .java file that will use classes from the jar file.

I run

```
    jar -tvf json-simple-1.1.1.jar
```

and I get

```
0 Sun Feb 19 14:30:56 CST 2012 org/
0 Sun Feb 19 14:30:56 CST 2012 org/json/
0 Sun Feb 19 14:30:56 CST 2012 org/json/simple/
3939 Sun Feb 19 14:30:54 CST 2012 org/json/simple/ItemList.class
2077 Sun Feb 19 14:30:54 CST 2012 org/json/simple/JSONArray.class
161 Sun Feb 19 14:30:54 CST 2012 org/json/simple/JSONAware.class
3076 Sun Feb 19 14:30:54 CST 2012org/json/simple/JSONObject.class
223 Sun Feb 19 14:30:54 CST 2012 org/json/simple/JSONStreamAware.class
3964 Sun Feb 19 14:30:54 CST 2012 org/json/simple/JSONValue.class
0 Sun Feb 19 14:30:56 CST 2012 org/json/simple/parser/
```

I want to implement ItemList.class, and I now know that it is in the package

```
    org/json/simple/
```

so in my .java file I do

```
    import org.json.simple.ItemList;

    public class Foo(){

    public static void main(String[]args){
    ItemList i = new ItemList();
        }
    }
```

I now need to compile Foo() so I run

```
    javac -cp '.;json-simple-1.1.1.jar' Foo.java
```

I get the error that the package org.json.simple does not exist but in github the class ItemList has package org.json.simple

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: put the jar on the classpath and import the class you need.

Comment: Am I not doing that with "import package.ItemList;" and javac -cp 'jar' Foo.java

Comment: why do you manually download jar files? You would save yourself a lot of (dependency) issues like this, if you used maven to do all that for you.

Comment: If you are using Linux, use colon `:` instead of semi-colon `;` in classpath.

Comment: Thanks! That worked

Answer (score 0):

If the jar is not in the same directory you need to give the path to the jar directory when specifying the class path.